# Sort and Filter double nested mongo array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a database entry similar to the below:

```
name: "List 1"
sections:[
        order:0
        name:"section 1"
            items : [Array
                visible:1
                name: "Item 1"
            ],
            visible:0
                name: "Item 2"
            ],
       
        order:0
        name:"section 2"
            items : [Array
                visible:1
                name: "Item 1"
            ],
            visible:1
                name: "Item 2"
            ]
            ...
```

I want to design a query in mongo that will let me

1. Order the sections according to the `sections.order` key
2. Filter out any items that have items.`visible !=1`. So far I've found that I can use unwind like this to reorder the `sections`, what I can't seem to find out is how to prevent the `items` with `visible !-1` from ending up in the result

Working Mongo Query to order the sections:

```
Record.aggregate([
    { $match: { name:name } },
    { $unwind: "$sections" },
   
    { $sort: { "sections.order": 1}, },
    {
      $group: {
        
        sections: { $push: "$sections" },
      },
    },
    {
      $project: {
        sections: "$sections",
      },
    },
  ])
```

The above query will order the sections correctly but I still get items with `visible:0` in there. Do you know how to filter out those items?

Comment: Please add valid sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new stage to filter items by visible

- `$addFields`, `$filter` to iterate loop of `items` and filter by `visible != 1`
- `$group` by `_id` and construct the sections array

```
Record.aggregate([
  { $match: { name: name } },
  { $unwind: "$sections" },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "sections.items": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$sections.items",
          cond: { $ne: ["$$this.visible", 1] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { "sections.order": 1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      name: { $first: "$name" },
      sections: { $push: "$sections" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wnmSJrAIr3t)